# Hadoop Debugging : Source Attachement

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I am trying to debug a simple Java Application to interface with HDFS. When I try to debug following line I am getting error source code not attached. How can I attach source code of an external Jar in this case and go inside that classes. (In this case Configuration class) ? I tried to specify the source jar in external libraries, but It didnt work.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:5070");

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf); // Setting up the required configurations
    Path p4 = new Path("/user/hdpuser/input/test.txt");
    if(fs.exists(p4))
    {
        System.out.println("File Exists");
    }
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can specify the source path. Got to Libraries , select a library and select external source path. ! It working !